# Can fresh Poblano peppers be used raw?

Tags: chili-peppers

I was thinking about making a pasta salad with roasted, peeled Poblanos and started to wonder if raw diced Poblanos might work and add a bit of crispness (texture) as bell peppers do.

Since I have only ever used Poblanos that have been roasted and peeled, I started searching for recipes. I haven't been able to find any recipes of any kind that use raw Poblanos.

At the same time, I haven't found anything that says there is any reason not to use them raw. So, I'm wondering if it's a taste or texture thing, or if there is any other reason.

Comment: You can eat them raw, but the skin's texture isn't nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The skin is thick and waxy. If you've got a vegetable peeler which takes off very thin slices, you could peel them. If you have a Brûlée torch or something similar, you could also just burn the skin off while keeping the flesh uncooked.

Comment: Or just the flame of a gas stove. In either case, it might be wise to avoid directly breathing in the smoke - depending on how sensitive you are, even a 3000 scoville pepper might be unpleasantly irritant...

Comment: @rackandboneman The flame of most home gas stoves isn't intense enough to burn the skin quick enough to avoid cooking the flesh. It's a great way to fire roast poblanos, but if you're looking for raw skinless poblanos, you really need a torch. I use a plumbing torch and get raw poblanos with no skin. I use my stove I get roasted poblanos.

Answer (score 2):

At between 1000-3500 on the [Scoville scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoville_scale) poblanos are certainly safe to use raw. Cleaning(removing the insides) would help to mellow them. Peeling them would probably be good, and that is challenging with a raw poblano. Torching them (per @SomeInterwebDev) to make them peel easily is a good idea, or just roast them...

Answer (score 2):

I just had a raw poblano along with some tinned corned mutton to which I had added a bit of Sri Lanken Maldive Fish Sambal.  A glass of water and a couple of corn tortillas completed my repast.  I have heard others complain about the tough skin of the poblano but it posed no problem for my teeth and was juicy, delicious, and had a faint hint of smokiness.  I enjoy them cooked too but raw is a nice change at times.